# appcenter stopped sending emails when distributing releases, any potential causes?

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-app-center-distribute

We use appcenter.ms to distribute an application (Xamarin, Android) to test groups. So far the center was sending emails to the users, when the release was distributed. It did stop doing so recently. Any idea why this could have happened?

Note - I have created another app and distributed a release from there. It did work, but the old app still does not email.

No error messages or anything else indicating what may be the issue.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/help

Comment: Good idea. I contacted them will see if this helps to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

There is a toggle now in setting where you can turn email notify on/off. Check if it has been turn off

Comment: Checked it. It does not seem to be a problem.